# calling an array in a function

Tags: php, email

I am having a function which has an array in it. I wanted to call that function foo and use the $result indexes (text, html, attachments) in my script. Please help me with this since I am totally new to php. I am trying to call the array to the mail() method. and getting error saying string expected and it id array. How can I insert the array to the relevant mail method.

```
function foo($a)    
{
    if (is_resource($b))
    {
        $result = array
        (
            'text' => null,
            'html' => null,
            'attachments' => array(),
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: your argument in function foo is `$a` but you're checking `$b`? o.o

Comment: So the issue is that you want the array shown in an email? Then the clue is in the error. In the main content you can add `print_r($arrayVar, true);`. If you want it custom formatted you'll need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass an array to the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function as it is expecting just strings. If you want the text of the email to be $result['text'], try

```
mail ($to, $subject, $result['text']
```

However, it looks like what are you trying is to have an array populate the attachments and content of an email. There's nothing like that out from the box in PHP. You may have to look for some third parties library. [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) maybe what you want.